# (Python - Scipy - Wave files) Can a float signal be written with values higher than 1?

Tags: python, scipy

While developing an application, I noticed strange behaviour while using scipy.io.wavfile to write audio files. The documentation says that floating-point data is written within a range between -1 and 1. However, files written this way seemingly can go past that. This is a MWE to illustrate what I mean:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.io import wavfile

# %% Writing supposedly saturated file

A = 2
f = 5
fs = 44100
t = np.linspace(0, 1, fs + 1)

testSignal = A * np.sin(2 * np.pi * f * t)

wavfile.write('test.wav', fs, testSignal.astype(float))


# %% Reading file with intact values 

_, writtenData = wavfile.read('test.wav')

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = [7.50, 3.50]
plt.rcParams["figure.autolayout"] = True

plt.plot(t, writtenData)
plt.ylabel("Signal")
plt.xlabel("Time")
plt.show()
```

[image: Signal imported from written file]

As you can see, even though I explicitly specified that the array past was to be in the floating-point format (and beyond -1 to 1), I was able to retrieve it without alterations.

After all, what gives? Are .wav files in float format really only capable of storing data between (-1,1)? Is there any hidden conversion going on that I might be missing out on?

TIA

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [WAV file format specifications](http://www-mmsp.ece.mcgill.ca/Documents/AudioFormats/WAVE/WAVE.html).

One option is for the file to store in `WAVE_FORMAT_IEEE_FLOAT` format. I suspect this is what the Python implementation is selecting, and why it works for other values like `A = 200`.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand what that means. I tried to look up this standard/format but I didn't find much about it that was informative. Does it use a different range of numbers? A different number of bits? Is it effectively extending the possibilities of values you can export to in .wav?

Comment: @JuhaP Not sure why the comment on the code says that 32bit floats have a maximum value of +1 and a minimum of -1. The *mantissa* component of the samples might be limited to that range, but there’s the *exponent* part that allows larger and smaller sizes.

Comment: Maybe `np.iinfo(np.float32).max` and `np.iinfo(np.float32).min` results the range for amplitude?

Comment: @JuhaP Possibly, but I get an error when I try that: `np.iinfo(np.float32)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/kootsoop/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/core/getlimits.py", line 656, in __init__
    raise ValueError("Invalid integer data type %r." % (self.kind,))
ValueError: Invalid integer data type 'f'.`. As it looks like `iinfo` is about [integer types](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.iinfo.html).

Comment: Aaa... , finfo() for float datatype ... float32 results [ -3.4028235e+38, 3.4028235e+38] so maybe not relation for the issue (float which OP used results [1.7976931348623157e+308, -1.7976931348623157e+308]. IIUC the python code, there's no functionality in write() function which would reduce the amplitude range to [-1,1].

Comment: @AlexandrePiccini : It means that the data type used is not an integer, but a floating point value. As Juha P shots in the comment above, the range of possible values for floating point numbers is definitely **not** -1 to +1. I believe the Python docs are wrong here, and [I've added a pull request to the source code maintainers to try to get it fixed.](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/pull/16515)

Comment: Range [-1,1] mentioned in the comments of source code may mean amplitude range (example code there sets amplitude to np.iinfo(np.int16).max) ... to get proper wave saved, range variable A should be given in range [-1,1]̣ in OP's code then.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply but I just saw this. I do give them somewhat the benefit of the doubt because audio is usually referred to as ranging from [-1,1] in most audio software, hence why the max of the dBFS scale is 0dB (since log(1/1) = 0). Maybe there's an implied proportionality constant applied that converts from the max values float allow to the arbitrary unit max for audio? In either way, that would also be inconsistent with the docs as they state other formats do store values beyond [-1,1], so something is surely missing. (P.S.: I'm aware of how float ranges work in the general case)

Comment: @AlexandrePiccini Right!  The file format can store larger values, but the players expect [-1,1].

Answer (score 0):

Usually the wave writer / parsers are not expected to perform any processing on the PCM data. In this case expectation was to normalize the data to [-1.0, 1.0] (or) clip the signal once it goes beyond -1.0 to 1.0.

Popular tools like audacity also accept such wavefiles with float PCM values beyond [-1.0, 1.0]. However, by definition the scale for float PCM is [-1.0, 1.0]. For the same reason, the signal "appears" as clipped form of the original when visualized using audacity(popular audio processing/editing tool). Please find below screen shot of "test.wav", generated using code snippet shared by You, when visualized using audacity

[image]

From the screen shot, the signal appears to be clipped giving an impression that audacity performed clipping  to the signal. In actual its not the case and it is the scale ([-1.0, 1.0]) that is the cause for this assumption.

Applying a gain of -6dB (since You chose amplitude to 2.0) gives the full sine signal as shown in the picture below.

[image]

As a conclusion, it looks like its not the responsibility of the wave creator (or) parser(in this case audacity parser) to actually carry out any pre(at the writer end) or post(at the reader end) processing on the data that is asked of them to write / read. It should be carried out at the application level calling these interfaces of wave reading or writing.